# How to Test ipv6 DNS Resolution Performance

Tags: domain-name-system

Is there any way to conduct IPv6 DNS resolution performance via some sort of bench marking process? With IPv4 there has been a couple of different tools such as GRC namebench and Google namebench but neither of them, nor any other tool I can find seems to be able to do anything similar to them. Has anyone found a tool or developed a process to test IPv6 DNS resolution performance with various DNS servers?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what kind of benchmark you're thinking of, particularly since you mention Google namebench, which already has a flag that tells it to only operate over IPv6.

Comment: I appologise, I am not sure how to make my statement any more clear. I am trying to perform the same benchmark for IPv6 DNS servers as the the applications listed in my post do for IPv4 DNS servers. I also do not see in the application or via google search an option to enable IPv6 benchmark with Googles namebench application.

Comment: @user1451070 What problems do you experience when you tell namebench to query an IPv6 address? If that is not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: Namebench doesn't seem to have the capability to do ipv6 addresses.

Comment: @user1451070 It seemed to work just fine when I tried it right now

Comment: GRC or Google, and if google, what OS?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a simple tool on GitHub: https://github.com/mwiora/NAMEinator

You can add as many ipv4 or ipv6 DNS-Servers as you like in the `nameserver-globals.csv`